# home.php or frontpage (via settings) for theme?

Tags: homepage, frontpage

OK. I'm getting conflicting instructions from my training resources (again).

This time the issue for me is **"how to set a default homepage"**.

One tutorial *(Coyers "WordPress 3: Creating and Editing Custom Themes")* **uses home.php**, while another *("Professional WordPress")* recommends setting "Front page displays..." via WordPress (Settings > Reading). ...aargh!

In checking the forums and blogs, I see the same issue: **conflicting advice**. With one user advising to **NEVER** use the home.php template page in a theme as *"[It can cause problems on some servers](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/homephp-instead-of-indexphp)"*. **Is this true?** And another user swearing by it.

...What is a noob to do?

So, given the confusion (and given that I'm a noob looking to do things the right way)...

1. What is the difference between the two approaches?
2. Which approach to a standard homepage should one use **when creating a theme**?

thanks,

sleeper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Simply put, the WordPress template hierarchy reserves `home.php` for the homepage, but if you set a Front Page post, it will display that instead. If WordPress core developers reserved it for the homepage, I do not believe it would cause issues with any servers, because they would be putting everyone at risk. Hope that explains it for you. :)
2. It is completely personal preference.

**From the WP Codex:**

1. WordPress first determines whether it has a static front page. If a
   static front page has been set, then WordPress loads that page
   according to the page template hierarchy.
2. If a static front page has not been set, then WordPress looks for a
   template file called home.php and uses it to generate the requested
   page.
3. If home.php is missing, WordPress looks for a file called index.php
   in the active theme's directory, and uses that template to generate
   the page.

See the relevant WordPress Codex page for more information:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: thanks for responding. Need a little clarity

"the WordPress template hierarchy reserves home.php for the homepage"

 so.. I CAN use home.php as the homepage of the site

"but if you set a Front Page post, it will display that instead."

 which I would NOT do if I choose to use home.php. Correct?
 
thanks

sleeper

Comment: @sleeper Basically it goes: 1) Static 'Front Page', 2) `home.php`, 3) `index.php` -- in that order. If 1 isn't there, it uses 2. If 2 isn't there, it uses 3.

Comment: And just a note, if you're using a static front-page, front-page.php takes precedence to home.php

Comment: @sleeper Glad you figured it out! If my answer lead you to the right place can you mark it as accepted please?

Comment: @Jared >> Sorry about the delay Jared (had a "life" interruption). Yes, it did lead me in the right direction. Marked as accepted.